# Why Eilenberg Maclane spaces $K(G,n)$ are $(n-1)$ connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, knot-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Why  Eilenberg Maclane spaces $K(G,n)$ are $(n-1)$ connected? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Isn't it almost the definition?

Comment: I do not understand the definition @Randall I am using 2 hard books (for me) which are AT and "modern classical homotopy theory " by Jeffery Strom.

Comment: A $K(G,n)$ has $\pi_n(K(G,n))=G$ and all others $0$, right?

Comment: yes @Randall I know this

Comment: How are you defining $k$-connectedness that isn't automatic from the definition fo the $K(G, n)$? (Proving that the spaces _exist_ is not automatic, but that's irrelevant.)

Comment: Isn't the definition of $X$ $(n-1)$-connected that $\pi_k(X) = 0$ for $k \leq n-1$?  Maybe that's not the definition you're working from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definitions say that $X$ is an Eilenberg-MacLane space of type $K(G,n)$ if $\pi_n(X)=G$ and $\pi_k(X)=0$ for all other $k$, and a space $X$ is $n$-connected if $\pi_k(X) = 0$ for all $k \leq n$ (for example "$0$-connected" means path-connected, and "$1$-connected" means simply-connected). If $\pi_k(X) = 0$ for all $k\neq n$, then $\pi_k(X)=0$ for all $k\leq n-1$ so it is $(n-1)$-connected.